# How to replace SQL Query CONDITION in Spring JPA native query

Tags: spring, jpa, native

I have a spring jpa native query(actual query has multiple tables connected) something like below.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="
select id, name from TABLE where id NOT IN ('2', '3')")
List<Object> getValueForNOTIN()

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="
select id, name from TABLE where id IN ('4', '5')")
List<Object> getValueForIN()
```

Instead of 2 methods, I want to use one method which replaces NOT IN and IN with this 'replaceClause' value.

```
List<Object> getValueForBoth(@Param("replaceClause)" String replaceClause)
```

I get error on start of server. Can't I do like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static string like

**private String SELECT_NOT_IN_QUERY = "select id, name from TABLE 
where id NOT IN ('id1', 'id2')"**

**private String SELECT_IN_QUERY = "select id, name from TABLE 
where id IN ('id1', 'id2')"**

then look for id1 and id2 and replace with its values. use the right static string accordingly.